# How can I suppress "Unapproved verbs" in Powershell classes

Tags: powershell

For using a class in a powershell (V7) script it seems necessary to declare the module, in which the class (Powershell language) is implemented, via

```
using module .\MyModule.psm1
```

The module "MyModule.psm1" imports a powershell module via

```
Import-Module powershell-yaml -DisableNameChecking
```

How can I suppress the "unapproved verbs" warnings during execution of the script ? The option DisableNameChecking does not seem to help here

Complete example of the module

```
 Import-Module powershell-yaml -DisableNameChecking

 class TestManager { 
 hidden [string] $NodeTypeApplication = "Application"

 TestManager () {
 }

 [void] StartDeployment()
 {
     Write-Host("starting deployment...")

 }

}
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this, please provide contents of a sample `psm1` file that exhibits this issue

Comment: yeah, it is not really my class, it seems that an module import within the module, containing the class, triggers the message. Have updated my question.

Comment: is that msg produced by PoSh itself or by PSReadline? if the 2nd, then you can define a custom rule to NOT show that msg.

Comment: it is produced by the shell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you do use `-DisableNameChecking` to import the *nested* module (`powershell-yaml`), **the warning can resurface for the *enclosing* module, if nonstandard functions from a *nested* module become part the enclosing module's exports**.

You have two options:

- **If you do need to export (nested) nonstandard functions** from your enclosing module:

  - **The only way to silence the warning for the enclosing module too is to import *it* with

    `Import-Module -DisableNameChecking` as well, rather than via `using module`**.
  - **Caveat**: Unfortunately, this **precludes using PowerShell *custom classes* defined in your module**; as of v7.0, custom classes only become visible to the importer if you use `using module` (see [GitHub issue #2449](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2449#issuecomment-255506786) for background information).
  - To solve this problem:

    - Define *wrapper* functions for those nonstandard functions you need to export and give them standards-compliant names.
    - Then exclude the nonstandard functions from your module's exports - see next point.
- **Otherwise, exclude the nonstandard functions from export**, which you can do in
  one of the following ways:

  - If you don't actually need them inside your enclosing module itself, exclude them from import by passing only the names of the functions you do need to the [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module)'s `-Function` parameter.
  - Otherwise, you can explicitly control what your enclosing module exports:

    - You can use an [`Export-ModuleMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/export-modulemember) call in your enclosing module.
    - Alternatively / additionally, you can restrict what functions are exported if you make your enclosing module use a [module manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-module-manifest) (`*.psd1` file).

---

Here's a simple demonstration of the original problem:

```
# Create a temp. nested module with a nonstandard function.
'function UnapprovedVerb-Foo { ''unapproved foo'' }' > tmp_nested.psm1

# Create the enclosing module that imports the nested module
# with warnings suppressed.
# However, because the enclosing module has no manifest, the nested
# functions are exported alongside its own functions.
'Import-Module $PSScriptRoot/tmp_nested.psm1 -DisableNameChecking; function Get-Foo { ''foo'' }' > tmp_enclosing.psm1

# This now triggers the warning - as import via `using module` would.
# Adding -DisableNameChecking would silence it, but `using module` has
# no equivalent mechanism - and you need the latter to import *custom PS classes*.
Import-Module ./tmp_enclosing.psm1
```